# фича у плагина emmet. Как сделать нумерацию

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, текст, sublime-text

В плагине emmet есть такая тема с множественными курсорами. Но как проделать с ними нумерацию строк под типа id="t20", id="t21", id="t22" и т.д.?
я знаю, что надо сделать несколько курсоров, потом нажать ctrl+shift+G и в консоли появится  а курсоры будут пронумерованы, но появятся теги. Как их убрать?
Там в консоли должно быть написано чтото типа ${newline @20} , но я забыл как точно это пишется, а в поисковике найти уже не могу. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так к примеру - `div#t2$*9`
[Docs](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)

Comment: ну какбы да, но как убрать div, чтобы были только цифры? И чтобы я набирал их в разном диапозоне. Ну типа начина с 1734 и тд

Comment: {$@}    <<== Вот! Сам нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так: `td*7{$@2}`

- `td*7` - создаст 7 TD
- `{$@15}` - создаст с 15 номера 7 TD